# C++ Change char variable in function

Tags: c++, function, char

When I run this, the numbers 1-9 don't change to either X or O when you pick them. They just stay as numbers. Is it a problem with trying to change the char values in a void function? Not sure how to accomplish this without using a void function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char vert = 0xB3;
char hori = 0xC4;
char cros = 0xC5;
char one = '1';
char two = '2';
char thr = '3';
char fou = '4';
char fiv = '5';
char six = '6';
char sev = '7';
char eig = '8';
char nin = '9';
char a;

void board()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << one << vert << two << vert << thr << endl
         << hori << cros << hori << cros << hori << endl
         << fou << vert << fiv << vert << six << endl
         << hori << cros << hori << cros << hori << endl
         << sev << vert << eig << vert << nin << endl;
}



void player1pick()
{
    cout << "First Player's turn. Please pick a box: ";
    cin >> a;
    if(a == 1)
    {
        one = 'X';
    }
    if(a == 2)
    {
        two = 'X';
    }
    if(a == 3)
    {
        thr = 'X';
    }
    if(a == 4)
    {
        fou = 'X';
    }
    if(a == 5)
    {
        fiv = 'X';
    }
    if(a == 6)
    {
        six = 'X';
    }
    if(a == 7)
    {
        sev = 'X';
    }
    if(a == 8)
    {
        eig = 'X';
    }
    if(a == 9)
    {
        nin = 'X';
    }
    board();
}

void player2pick()
{
    cout << "Second Player's Turn. Please pick a box: ";
    cin >> a;
    if(a == 1)
    {
        one = 'O';
    }
    if(a == 2)
    {
        two = 'O';
    }
    if(a == 3)
    {
        thr = 'O';
    }
    if(a == 4)
    {
        fou = 'O';
    }
    if(a == 5)
    {
        fiv = 'O';
    }
    if(a == 6)
    {
        six = 'O';
    }
    if(a == 7)
    {
        sev = 'O';
    }
    if(a == 8)
    {
        eig = 'O';
    }
    if(a == 9)
    {
        nin = 'O';
    }
    board();
}

int main()
{
    board();
    player1pick();
    player2pick();
    player1pick();
    player2pick();
    player1pick();
    player2pick();
    player1pick();
    player2pick();
    player1pick();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried print out the `one`,`two` just before and after they change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because a is a char and you compare it with 1 which is a number. For example, when player enters fo 1 as an input, '1' gets stored in a (which is 49 in ascii). And when you do comparison, e.g. `if(a == 1)` it basically compares ascii value of '1' with 1.... so `49 == 1` which is of course false. Sou, you either have to change type of a to int, or compare char with char - `a == '1'`.

Comment: Yep, this seems to happen regularly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you are comparing the users input you are comparing a character value (say `'1'` with an integewr value `1`), which (in most cases) will not be equal.

Change your comparisons to `if (a == '1')` and so on...

Also, you might want to tink about storing the board cells (your variables one to nin) in some sort of a collection (array, std::vector, etc.) for easier handling and possible expantion later on.

Answer (score 0):

change `char a;` to `int a;`
it interpret it as chars

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing ascii values of characters with numbers which is fine by the compiler but I don't think that's what you want. So either change `char a to int`

or change comparisons to `a=='1'`

I would suggest you replace all the if statements with an [array](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/),

```
int a;
char numbers[9] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
```

in the functions you could do:

```
cin >> a;
numbers[a] = 'O';
```